# Identification of IC, top marking 200R0 B B1936-

Tags: identification

What does this "V" represent?

[image: Close up photo]

[image: Photo of component]

Comment: It's a resistor 200R0 means 200ohms. 2R2 would mean 2.2ohms. The "R" is equivalent to a decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the *Vishay* branding.

Here is a similar 100 Ω resistor: [Vishay Foil Resistors 100Ω Metal Foil SMD Resistor ±0.01% 0.25W - SMR1D 100R 0,01%](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/surface-mount-resistors/3468370)

[image: Vishay 100Ω Metal Foil SMD Resistor]